# Is there a way to "toggle" between desktops on mac OS?

Tags: keyboard, desktop

I know there are many ways to activate/modify keyboard shortcuts to switch between specific desktops, such as desktop 1, desktop 2, etc. However, I would like to figure out a way to just "toggle" between my desktops if possible. I typically only have 2 desktops that are being used, so just a single shortcut to go back and forth between 1 and 2 would be perfect.

Specifically looking to map this to my Logitech G502 custom key.

Comment: **macOS** does not have a default method of toggling between two **Desktops/Spaces** using a single _keyboard shortcut_. One would need to _script/code_ something and or use a _third-party utility_ to achieve the goal. To that end... 1. What version of **macOS** are you running? 2. Is the **[] Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use** _checkbox_ in **System Preferences** > **Mission Control** checked or unchecked? 3. Is this a single display or multiple display environment?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks a lot for this information. I'm using macOS Big Sur v11.5.2. The checkbox is enabled in System Preferences. This is a single display environment.

Comment: RE: "Specifically looking to map this to my Logitech G502 custom key." -- As I do not have this device I cannot address it except to say you should probably provide the details of what this device is capable of, assuming it has a software interface to add a custom function, what can it do/how does it do do it?  In other words, can it execute a _script_ and if so what language, etc.?

Comment: With the **[√] Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use** _checkbox_ in **System Preferences** > **Mission Control** checked, that may be problematic to some possible solutions. Do you need to have it checked?

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks. It does have some capabilities to do "custom" things, but not really in a "toggle" faction per se. So I can map the "ctrl + right arrow" as a key binding to this button, but that doesn't solve it for when the next desktop is back to the left. I don't have to have this checkbox enabled. Not actually sure why it was enabled to begin with to be honest.

Comment: RE: "Not actually sure why it was enabled to begin with to be honest. " -- It's enabled by default.

Comment: Question... Can it be assigned another _modifier key_, e.g. _command+right-arrow_ or _option+right-arrow_? I'm asking because using e.g. _command+right-arrow_ I can have **Hammerspoon** detect the _keyboard shortcut_ and in turn check which is the current **Desktop/Space**, 1 or 2, and switch between the two each time _command+right-arrow_ is pressed, or in this case when the mouse button is clicked. This is of course dependent on whether it's detectable when done by mouse button. My guess is that it would be, however, I of course cannot test that. You'd have to check before I write the code.

Comment: Does the G-Hub software have 'smart combinations'? My MX [which runs on Logi Options not G-Hub] I can hold a button & swipe the mouse left or right to change spaces.